# How to get the range of first paragraph on each page in Word Document using C# Word interlop

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a word file with 9 pages.

I use this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(file);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range docRange = wordDoc.Range();
```

But, this code will give me range of all paragraph.

How to get the range of text in fist line (or first paragraph) of each page using C# Word interlop?

Sorry about my english ...

**Ex:**
At the first page i want to get text:

> "*Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company
>   headquartered in Cupertino, California,*"

or first paragraph

> "*Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company
>   headquartered in Cupertino, California, that designs, develops, and
>   sells consumer electronics, computer software, and online services. It
>   is considered one of the Big Four technology companies, alongside
>   Amazon, Google, and Microsoft.*"

[image]

The second page is:

the Text i want:

> Apple was founded by Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak, and Ronald Wayne in
>   April 1976 to develop and sell

or

> *Apple was founded by Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak, and Ronald Wayne in April 1976 to develop and sell Wozniak's Apple I personal computer,
>   though Wayne sold his share back within 12 days.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try iterate through all paragraphs and get page number. Then select the first paragraph of the page.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

private void FindFirstParagraphOfEachPage()
{
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);
    Word.Range docRange = wordDoc.Range();

    var paragraphs = new List<Paragraph>();

    foreach (Word.Paragraph p in wordDoc.Paragraphs)
    {
        paragraphs.Add(new Paragraph()
        {
            PageNumber = (int)p.Range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber),
            ParagraphText = p.Range.Text.ToString()
        });
    }
    var result = paragraphs.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ParagraphText))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.PageNumber)
                        .Select(x => x.First());

    wordDoc.Close();
    wordApp.NormalTemplate.Saved = true;
    wordApp.Quit();
}
```

Helper class to store page number and paragraph text.

```
class Paragraph
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string ParagraphText { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure about releasing the objects. It probably will require some edits and testing.

Comment: Thanks. I was successful!